# Revisions in google cloud storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to save my files to google cloud storage. I have stored my files like this name doc_personId_fileId. But now If my user uploads another file old file will be replaced. I want to keep revisions. What is best approach to keep record of all the revisions. For example:

I have a file named doc_1_1. Now if user uploads another file. Old file should be named as doc_1_1_revision_1 and after that doc_1_1_revision_2 and so on and new file should be doc_1_1.

What is best method to save this?
Or is there anything provided by google to handle this type of scenarios?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to upload `doc_1_1` a few times, for example 3 times, and expect your bucket to look like:

> - doc_1_1
> - doc_1_1_revision_3
> - doc_1_1_revision_2
>     . . .

In short, you cannot achieve this automatically by GCP supports and it requires you work around your upload code to do 2 operations :

- [moving](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects) the old file to name it with `revision`
- upload the new file

Alternatively, GCP support [object revision](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) using two concepts `generation` on the object itself and `metageneration`on meta-data associated with the object. So you either keep uploading new file and do not need to pay attention to other revisions but leave it to GCP to handle. Listing files with [option](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#view) to see `generation` and `metadata` will give you all files and revisions

Of course, you can [restore / retrieve](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#copy) a file with specfiying the revision

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is:

> I have a file named doc_1_1. Now if user uploads another file. Old
>   file should be named as doc_1_1_revision_1 and after that
>   doc_1_1_revision_2 and so on and new file should be doc_1_1.

Google Cloud Storage does not support this naming technique. You will have to implement this on the client side as part of your upload process.

Another option is to enable "Object Versioning" where previous objects with the same name still persist. The last uploaded instance is the "current" version.

This link will help you understand object versions:

[Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning)